# RuntimeError: Attempted to set the storage of a tensor on device "cuda:0" to a storage on different device "cpu"

Tags: python, pytorch

Earlier I have configured the following project

**https://github.com/zllrunning/face-makeup.PyTorch**

using Pytorch with CUDA=10.2, Now Pytorch with CUDA=10.2 support is not available for Windows.
So, when I am configuring the same project using Pytorch with CUDA=11.3, then I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempted to set the storage of a tensor on device "cuda:0" to a storage on different device "cpu".  This is no longer allowed; the devices must match.
```

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: As the error clearly states, you will have to modify the project to use the current PyTorch semantics for managing the memory space where data is stored. This isn't a CUDA related problem in any way, it is just trying to run outdated code on a modern version of Pytorch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding `map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage.cuda()` in the `model_zoo.load_url` method. I think in torch 1.12 they have changed the default location from GPU to CPU (which does not make any sense).

Edit:
In the file resnet.py, under function **def init_weight(self):**, the following line

**state_dict = modelzoo.load_url(resnet18_url)**

is changed with

**state_dict = modelzoo.load_url(resnet18_url, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage.cuda())**

Answer (score 1):

not specifically related to resnet , but below code should work for majority of issues related to " dont know how to restore data location of torch.storage._untype storage ( tagged with gpu)

```
import torch  
import whisper 
devices = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") 
model = whisper.load_model("medium" , device =devices)
```